# Github pull request issue "This comparison is taking too long to generate" with project using RASA framework

Tags: github

I have this issue when I try to merge my branch to the main one for my RASA chatbot project and I want to know if there are any ways to fix this and create a pull request or should I just change my main branch to the domain-side branch

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I fixed the issue by deleting the .rasa cache folder

Comment: You probably also want to add .rasa to your .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when there are a lot of commits in your Pull Request

Unfortunately, this is a known github issue.

> Thanks for writing to GitHub support and sorry for the trouble!
>
> We have received a few similar reports regarding big pull requests. I can confirm that our team is working on fixing this problem, and I've added your report to that issue.
>
> Unfortunately I won't be able to provide an estimated time on when this might get fixed. We know this is not ideal, but hope you understand.
>
> Is there anything we can do to preserve our comments and alleviate this issue now and in the future?
>
> You should be able to use our API to get a copy of the comments in this pull request:
>
> ```
> https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#list-comments-on-a-pull-request
>
> https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request
> ```
>
> If you have any question regarding using API we can definitely offer more detailed instructions.
>
> Unfortunately I'm not sure if there's anything you can do on your part to view this pull request normally.
>
> One thing you could try is viewing this PR in Incognito window or logged out.
>
> I was actually able to view the PR you linked because I don't have write access to this repository, so GitHub will try to load less things for me such as edit buttons and so on. Of course this won't allow you to merge the pull request and so on, but perhaps it would help for you to look at its content?
>
> Lastly, while we are working on consistently supporting large pull requests, you might consider keeping pull requests relatively short for now to avoid running into this again.
>
> I hope this helps clear things up, and please let us know if you have any other questions.

Please refer to the full discussion provided [here](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/3125).